# Measure heterogeneity of groups in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have a dataframe and I created 3 groups based on the value variable following the fisher-jenks classification.
Now I am supposed to measure the within and between groups variances.
How can I do so ?

Here's my dataset :

```
dput(data)

structure(list(Id = c(46977, 47055, 47133, 47211, 47289, 47367, 
47445, 47523, 47601, 47679, 47757, 47835, 47913, 47991, 48069, 
48147, 48225, 48303, 48381, 48459, 48537, 48615, 48693, 48771, 
48849, 48927, 49005, 49083, 49161, 49239, 49317, 49395, 49436, 
49477, 49518, 49559, 49600, 49641, 49682, 49723, 49764, 49805, 
49846, 49887, 49928, 49969, 50010, 50051, 50092), Valeurs = c(101.3, 
105.7, 98.7, 111.8, 109.1, 121.7, 105.5, 119.7, 135.6, 124.2, 
121.1, 120.1, 109.4, 107.5, 102, 100.6, 101, 108.7, 98.6, 115.9, 
97.2, 96.1, 109, 107.8, 100, 97.6, 97.5, 103.3, 104.3, 103.7, 
111.6, 124.2, 98.6, 99.3, 100.3, 105.7, 105.4, 102.8, 101.7, 
99, 97.3, 102.1, 109.1, 102, 97.1, 97, 95.4, 96.7, 111.6), Group = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -49L
))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Read about ANOVA.

Comment: Have you already tried something like `summary(aov(Valeurs ~ Group, data = data))`? PS: it's not a good idea to call your data-set `data`, because `data` already exists in R.